# Exports defaults else path not taken with Jest and ES6

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, istanbul

I'm having issues to pass my tests with 100% coverage. Istanbul say that `exports defaults Component` else path not taken.

Because of that, I see in my generated html of istanbul that my tests are not completely at 100%. Mostly in the Statements and Branches tab.

I'm using:

- React: 15.4.0
- Jest: 17.0.2
- Webpack: 1.12.11

Any idea?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the jest configuration, we were using a preprocessor in order to resolve some imports:

In the package json we had this:

```
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/cfg/preprocessor.js"
},
```

This file contained this:

```
const babelJest = require('babel-jest');
require('babel-register');
const webpackAlias = require('jest-webpack-alias');

module.exports = {
  process: function (src, filename) {
    if (filename.indexOf('node_modules') === -1) {
      src = babelJest.process(src, filename);
      src = webpackAlias.process(src, filename);
    }
    return src;
  }
};
```

We updated to Jest `v20` and also use the module resolver from Jest, in our `package.json` we added:

```
"moduleDirectories": [
  "node_modules",
  "src"
],
```

and removed the `transform` config from the `package.json` and the `preprocessor.js` file.