# Coverage reports 'Else path not taken' on an imported provider

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am losing my mind with the error. I am on react-native with jest (and no ts). I have a localization provider which exports several methods, including translations. translations is simply:

```
      import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';
      translations = new LocalStrings({en,de});
```

in my components, I do:

```
       import { LocalizationContext } from './localization';
       const { translations } = useContext(LocalizationContext);
```

now when running on my component, the whole import line is marked with about 6 E I E I

First, given I am only using translations, why are there more than one if and else to cover? and secondly, tranlations is set from LocalStrings of a third party library? should it even be tested?

I saw this question [about jest config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660511/exports-defaults-else-path-not-taken-with-jest-and-es6) which advises about removing transform node from jest config but when i do it the whole test just stops with errors.

My jest config is:

```
{
    "preset": "react-native",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text",
      "cobertura",
      "lcov",
      "json"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native-community/.*|react-navigation|react-navigation-drawer|@react-navigation/.*))"
    ]
  }
```

My component simply outputs a provided value with no logic and there are no coverage notes at all except for the import.

Comment: Anything new there?